# Como detectar una url diferente y así poder redireccionar en AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy utilizando `$routeProvider` para las rutas en [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) y quiero detectar una `url` o ruta diferente a las establecidas en este código y así poder redireccionar al home cada vez que la ruta no este definida.

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{  
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'                
        })          
}])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agrega :

```
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
})
```

Con `.otherwise` estableces una ruta que se utilizará cuando suceda un cambio de ruta y esta no este definida en la configuración de tu aplicación angular. Al parámetro `redirecTo` le indicamos la ruta establecida para lo explicado anteriormente.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',{  
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html'            
        })                     
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
}])
```